# Why are git clone --bare and --origin incompatible?

Tags: git

I'm sure there must be a good reason, but I don't understand why I can't set the name of my origin in bare repos.

Comment: FTFM: Also the branch heads at the remote are copied directly to corresponding local branch heads, without mapping them to `refs/remotes/origin/`. When this option is used, **neither remote-tracking branches nor the related configuration variables are created.**  -- so there's no "origin" to rename.

Comment: I guess that explains why fetch is a little weirder for remote repos and require specifying a complete refspec (+<local-ref>:<remote-ref>). Not sure _why_ it's done this way, though....

Comment: I note that you can still add a remote, and maybe that's what I need to do...

Comment: Note (2022, 9 years later): `git clone --bare` and `--origin` are now actually compatible!. See [my edited answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19444098/6309), which will be valid with Git 2.39+ (Q4 2022)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2013: As [jthil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1290731/jthill) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19434441/why-are-git-clone-bare-and-origin-incompatible#comment28817530_19434441), and as it is implemented since [git 1.2.0 (January 2006)](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4fb66a62eeb7bfec115cd0058d7a05ab62fc23e7)

> `clone`: do not create `remotes/origin` nor `origin` branch in a bare repository.
> It is simply pointless, since no merges will ever happen in such a repository.

That doesn't prevent you to *add* a remote, as [git1.6.0 (August 2008)](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bc699afcce3c45bb17aaca145d081992ed699a42) shows with the `--mirror` option.

> The command line `git clone --mirror $URL` is now a short-hand for:

```
$ git clone --bare $URL
$ (cd $(basename $URL) && git remote add --mirror origin $URL)
```

---

### Update 2022: `git clone --bare` and `--origin` ARE compatible!

Before Git 2.39 (Q4 2022, 9 years later), "[`git clone`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/7aeb0d4c47878a04e19cffe2ddf20d642df56414/Documentation/git-clone.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone))</sup> did not like to see the `--bare` and the `--origin` options used together without a good reason.

That is no longer the case:

See [commit 3b910d6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3b910d6e2911a48a2a6945094f79dacd5367b799) (22 Sep 2022) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 7aeb0d4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7aeb0d4c47878a04e19cffe2ddf20d642df56414), 10 Oct 2022)</sup>

> ### [`clone`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3b910d6e2911a48a2a6945094f79dacd5367b799): allow "--bare" with "-o"
>
> <sup>Reported-by: John A. Leuenhagen</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jeff King</sup>

> We explicitly forbid the combination of "`--bare`" with "`-o`", but there doesn't seem to be any good reason to do so.
> The original logic came as part of [e6489a1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e6489a1bdf6e20371e6cd6497918f1c1198d5f81) ("`clone`: do not accept more than one -o option.", 2006-01-22, Git v1.2.0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/92643a27cc2cc7ce55ba2afd6155f94b40e1aa89)), but that commit does not give any reason.
>
> Furthermore, the equivalent combination via config is allowed:
>
> ```
> git -c clone.defaultRemoteName=foo clone ...
> ```
>
> and works as expected.
> It may be that this combination was considered useless, because a bare clone does not set `remote.origin.fetch` (and hence there is no `refs/remotes/origin` hierarchy).
> But it does set `remote.origin.url`, and that name is visible to the user via "[`git fetch origin`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/3b910d6e2911a48a2a6945094f79dacd5367b799/Documentation/git-fetch.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch))</sup>, et